# I want some of the content in my page to be crawlable but should not be indexed

Tags: indexing, web-crawler, seo, google-crawlers, google-index

Problem:

- A have page like https://websiteurl/person/{person}, where there is some content(which includes  images, description) related to that person and within this page there is one section called **(related persons)** which includes links to other persons page.
- Now when i search that person's name in google search , it shows that persons name and images but **along with that it also shows other person image** with that and we don't want that.
- So, for that i want crawlers to crawler those related person link but don't want to associated with that persons page(do not index related persons links with give person's page).

Discarded solution:
using meta tag robot no index will not work. as it works on page level and we don't want entire page to be non indexable.